# Should the user be given an option to scan or read an article?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, content, portfolio

I am working on my portfolio website and I wanted to allow the user (colleague/recruiter) to either scan or read the case studies. How to I validate this feature?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What do you mean by scan? I'm sorry, but am not sure I understand.

Comment: Apologies for late reply. By scan i mean skim through the content. For example, most of the people do not read the news paper completely. They 'scan' by flipping the papers and read whatever catches the eye.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is inherent in any website and should be solved using proper Information Architecture for the site and the content. If it is about a case study particularly, the format could follow your actual process step by step. In terms of presentation, an Index may be used to arrive at a particular point on the page. You can try using coloured text or particular text-style to emphasise important points from the story. You can also add an 'Excerpt' at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the usage of the portfolio scanning is the best way, where it allows the users to grab the over all idea of the projects and working.

Case 1 (Recruiter)

when it comes to recruiter, he / she probably want to spend less time to view the portfolio also, there will be a-lot of portfolio to view for recruitment, in that case if the portfolio is very large the probability of neglecting is more, so its better to maintain the portfolio small and sharp content.

By maintaining the portfolio small, it gives an opportunity to meet the recruiter in person and express our thoughts about the project in a better way.

Case 2 (colleague)

As in the case of colleague, when we consider normal person behaviours, most of people avoid reading the whole content and they tend to scan or listen to the content through audio communication, so i consider making the portfolio as small and easy.
Possibility of meeting the colleague or working together will be more often, hence you can explain the process better.